# Compare two json object and fetch data from one into another based on matching key

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two json response something like this, basically need to pull the 'status' from res2 and insert into res1 based on matching **uid**

```
res1 = [
  {
    uid: 'RBZ7K2122715',
    Model: Mod1,
    lastReceived: date1
  },
  {
    uid: 'RBZ7K2123333',
    Model: Mod2,
    lastReceived: date2
  }
]

res2 = [
  {
    uid: 'RBZ7K2122715',
    Status: [ [Object1], [Object2], [Object3] ]
  },
  {
    vin: 'RBZ7K2123333',
    Status: [ [Object4], [Object5] ]
  }
]
```

I'd like to get response something like this:

```
result = [
      {
        uid: 'RBZ7K2122715',
        Model: Mod1,
        lastReceived: date1,
        Status: [ [Object1], [Object2], [Object3] ]
      },
      {
        uid: 'RBZ7K2123333',
        Model: Mod2,
        lastReceived: date2,
        Status: [[Object4], [Object5]]
      }
    ]
```

In case any particular uid is not present in res1 but present in res2 in that case populate res1 fileds with 'N/A' and vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can group by `uid` and merge the items.

```js
const res1 = [
  {
    uid: 'RBZ7K2122715',
    Model: 'Mod1',
    lastReceived: 'date1'
  },
  {
    uid: 'RBZ7K2123333',
    Model: 'Mod2',
    lastReceived: 'date2'
  }
];

const res2 = [
  {
    uid: 'RBZ7K2122715',
    Status: [ ['Object1'], ['Object2'], ['Object3'] ]
  },
  {
    vin: 'RBZ7K2123333',
    Status: [ ['Object4'], ['Object5'] ]
  }
];

const groupBy = [...res1, ...res2].reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.uid] ? acc[cur.uid] = {
    ...acc[cur.uid], ...cur
  } : acc[cur.uid] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});

const output = Object.values(groupBy);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop `res1` using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),  find the `res2`'s item that has the same uid and return the new object.

```js
const result = res1.map(item => {
  const index = res2.findIndex(item2 => item2.uid === item.uid)
  return {
    ...item,
    Status: index !== -1 ? res2[index].Status : []
  }
});
```

Comment: You are missing a character on your 5th line sir.

Comment: Code only answers are marked as low quality and are subject for deletion. Add some context/explanation to your answer in order to remove it from low quality posts and avoid deletion.

Comment: @WilliamWang thanks. if any uid is not present in res2 but present in res1 then how it will handle?

Comment: just updated answer, if uid is not find in res2, passed empty array.

Comment: @WilliamWang but one thing, if uid is present in res2 but not present in res1 then it's ignoring that uid in output. In such cases model,lastreceived should be null but status should have records.